# Java spring exception handling when the compiler says it needs to wrapped in a try catch

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, try-catch

Im using Spring to handle my exceptions in the controller class with @ExceptionHandler
I have a transport class (similar to a DAO) with the following

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(getMethod);
```

the compiler is complaining that it needs to be in a try catch.
If I add `throws Exception` to the method signature it stops this warning but then how do I handle the close of the client (DefaultHttpClient).

NB. There is also a BuffererdInputStream that would need to be closed.

I guess I've made this a 2 part question:

1. Whats the best way to deal with exceptions when the compiler is complaining (remember I'm using Spring to handle them in the controller)
2. If I use `throws Exception` in the method signature, how do I
   **nicely** close off my connections.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
public void someMethod() throws SomeException {
    try {
        // ...
    } finally {
        // cleanup
    }
}
```

Lombok [`@Cleanup`](http://projectlombok.org/features/Cleanup.html) is also a nice way to clean things up.

By the way, I strongly advise you to take a look at [`RestTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) and replace your `HttpClient` with it